# Error when managing pinned Nix packages using niv

Tags: package, nix, nix-shell

I'm starting to learn how to use `nix-shell` in order for me to have reproductibles envs for dev and devops operations.

I'm trying to have a `shell.nix` file with pinned packages version (`kustomize` v3.6.1, `git` X.Y.Z etc.), but I can't make it work. Basically, what I would like is being able to pin tools versions instead of nixpkgs version.

I followed `niv` Getting Started instructions on their repo to:

1. Create a new project using `niv init` -> this worked well
2. Add a new package using `niv add stedolan/jq` -> this seemed to work well too, as the `sources.json` got updated.

Then I edited my `shell.nix` as follows:

```hs
let
  sources = import ./nix/sources.nix;
  pkgs = import sources.nixpkgs { };
  jq = import sources.jq { };
in

pkgs.mkShell {
    buildInputs = [
        pkgs.vim
        pkgs.niv
        jq
    ];
}
```

But everytime I try to run `nix-shell`, I have the following error message:

```
error: opening file '/nix/store/lz1m9sv79l0d0lkjm2acnxyx1avnzahk-jq-src/default.nix': No such file or directory
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

I tried digging into the docs of both Nix and Niv, reading blog posts etc. but to be honest I'm feeling like I'm [learning how to draw an owl](https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/572/078/d6d.jpg).

Any idea how I can solve this? Thanks a lot!

Some more infos:

```
$ nix-shell --version
nix-shell (Nix) 2.13.3
$ niv --version
0.2.22
$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
```

Comment: `stedolan/jq` refers to the github project, not the `jq` package in nixpkgs. And the `stedolan/jq` github repo has no `default.nix` present in the root directory. Hence the error.

You likely wanted to refer to `pkgs.jq` instead.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski thanks for the explaination! So is there a way for me to have `jq` in a given version and, let's say, `git` in another one without having to import multiple versions of `nixpkgs`?  I thought that was the main goal of the `source.json` file, but I guess I'm wrong

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by version. git and jq are two different programs. You can refer to two different nixpkgs versions, just add the second one, and refer to it.